# Draw a line along a road in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw a line along a road in google maps v2 in Android. So I did a search on this and found these sample codes in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710744/how-to-draw-road-directions-between-two-geocodes-in-android-google-map-v2) 
but unfortunately both of these examples are not worked for me. The first one gave me a forced close exception.
Does anybody have working example of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your force close .. logcat..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I looked log cat and able to fix the issue

Comment: I found complete working sample here:: 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Comment: This is good but.. try to solve your bug first yourself..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17587884/1318946

Comment: what have been you tried

Answer (score 5):

first create normal Googlemaps V2 app, in that call a method

**1)** String myurl = makeURL(source_latitude, source_longitude, destinaton_latitude, destinaton_longitude);

```
public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog) {
                StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
                urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
                urlString.append("?origin=");// from
                urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
                urlString.append("&destination=");// to
                urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
                return urlString.toString();
        }
```

**2) Call a Async Task**

new connectAsyncTask(myurl).execute();

Async class

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> 
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;

        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) 
        {
    url = urlPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
        if (result != null) {
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**3)** **To Draw a path**

```
public void drawPath(String result) {

        try {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

            for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
                LatLng src = list.get(z);
                LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
                Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude)).width(4).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
```

**4)** Now create a new class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();`enter code here`
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
                BufferedReader reader = new 
                        BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```